# BigInteger modulus not positive

Tags: java, biginteger, factorization

```
public static BigInteger primeFactorOf(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger p = n.sqrt();
    BigInteger small = new BigInteger("0");
    BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
    while(n.mod(p).compareTo(small)!=0){
        p=p.subtract(two);
    }
    System.out.println(p);
    System.out.println(n.divide(p));
   return p;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
   BigInteger big = new BigInteger("3223956689869297");
   primeFactorOf(big);
}
```

Got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger: modulus not positive
at java.base/java.math.BigInteger.mod(BigInteger.java:2692)
at matma.primeFactorOf(matma.java:125)
at matma.main(matma.java:136)
```

I made this function to factor big number on two prime numbers (in this case `82192031*39224687=3223956689869297`).

While the function worked for smaller numbers (when primes where 6-digit) now when i used 8-digit primes i have this error.

I don't understand why and how it worked before and now it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the fact that sqrt(3223956689869297) is an even number. The primes factors of 3223956689869297 are all odd numbers. As you are going down by 2 each time, you are only looking at even numbers, and skipping over the prime factors. Eventually, the modulus (p) goes from 2 to 0 and you get this error (modulus not positive).

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about this, i thought that substracting 2 will be enough and it would make program faster